# Plotting mutliple plots: Different max and min for continuous color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

In my real data, I have a PCA plot that I want to color in 50 different ways, based on the score all of my points have for 50 different hallmarks. The scores differs a lot between the different hallmarks, so I want every plot to have their own max and min value for the continuous color scale.

This works if I use for instance a rainbow color gradient, but since I want to look for "high" and "low", I want to have a blue-grey-red-scale. When I make this by using `scale_color_gradient2`, the max and min value is set based on all data, and not per Hallmark. See sample code below:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=4)) %>% 
  cbind(.,data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20)*5, nrow=4)) ) %>% 
  add_column(HALLMARK= c("HALLMARK1","HALLMARK2","HALLMARK3","HALLMARK4"), .before = 1) %>% 
  gather(key=Patient, value= Value , -HALLMARK) %>% 
  cbind(., data.frame(Value2=matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=20)))
```

This works, but with wrong colors:

```
test.plots <- df %>% 
  group_by(HALLMARK) %>%
  do(
    plots=  ggplot(data=., mapping=aes(x=Value, y=Value2))+
  geom_point(.,mapping=aes(color=Value))+
  geom_text(.,mapping=aes(label=Patient, color=Value))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors = rainbow(3))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())+
    facet_wrap(~HALLMARK)
  )

test.plots$plots
```

This does not work how I want it to, but the colors are correct:

```
 test.plots <- df %>% 
  group_by(HALLMARK) %>%
  do(
    plots=  ggplot(data=., mapping=aes(x=Value, y=Value2))+
  geom_point(.,mapping=aes(color=Value))+
  geom_text(.,mapping=aes(label=Patient, color=Value))+
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=median(.$Value), mid="grey", low= "red", high="blue" )+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())+
    facet_wrap(~HALLMARK)
  )

test.plots$plots
```

Can someone help me? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your code is really not straight forward e.g. why facetting...but this is another problem.  Try `scale_colour_gradientn(colors = c("grey","red","blue" ))`? Then try `ggplot(df, aes(x=Value, y=Value2,label=Patient, color=Value))+
      geom_point()+
      geom_text()+
      scale_colour_gradientn(colors = c("grey","red","blue" ))+
      facet_wrap(~HALLMARK)`

Comment: Thanks, your solution works for my test data, but somehow not for my real data. I only get a warning message saying `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` for your first suggestion, and the second one gives `mapping must be created by aes()`.

(The facetting was just a quick-fix solution for getting a header telling me which Hallmark the plot shows :) )

Comment: This `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` is a factor vs. numeric problem in your data.frame. Check `str()`. You have to specify all mappings including x,y, fill, color, facet in `aes()`. Thus, check names of your columns.

Comment: Nice, now it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functioning solution given by @Jimbou :

```
test.plots <- df %>% 
  group_by(HALLMARK) %>%
  do(
    plots=  ggplot(data=., mapping=aes(x=Value, y=Value2))+
  geom_point(.,mapping=aes(color=Value))+
  geom_text(.,mapping=aes(label=Patient, color=Value))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors = c("grey","red","blue" ))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())+
    facet_wrap(~HALLMARK)
  )

test.plots$plots
```